# How to use .msg in source code as a variable?

Tags: ros, c++, nav-msgs, msg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to use nav_msg/GridCells.msg and OccupancyGrid in my package,How to use it in the source code. It is not a member of nav_msgs and it is only a .msg and I am unable find documentation for using GridCells as a member variable i.e. I want to initialize occupancy grid and add data to it and publish it as a topic. I want to do in cpp.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/103716/how-to-use-.msg-in-source-code-as-a-variable?/) by [balakumar-s](https://answers.ros.org/users/5452/balakumar-s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 137 on 2013-11-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-11-27**:
@balakumar-s please accept the question by using the checkbox at the left of the answer instead of closing it. (the checkbox will implicitly close it, and reward the answerer with karma.

**Comment by [balakumar-s](https://answers.ros.org/users/5452/balakumar-s/) on 2013-11-27**:
@tfoote Thanks I did that now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What have you tried so far? What isn't working?

The [c++ publisher/subscriber tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp_tutorials/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber) shows how to create a ros message, add data to it, and then publish it.

---

Originally posted by [lindzey](https://answers.ros.org/users/2444/lindzey/) with karma: 1780 on 2013-11-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [balakumar-s](https://answers.ros.org/users/5452/balakumar-s/) on 2013-11-21**:
I just initialized as :
nav_msgs::OccupancyGrid og;
og.data=temp_data;
but the error while compiling is
OccupancyGrid is not a member of nav_msgs
Is this how you initialize? Is OccupancyGrid not a member and cant it be used like a class?

**Comment by [lindzey](https://answers.ros.org/users/2444/lindzey/) on 2013-11-21**:
If you want help debugging why your code won't compile, you need to edit your original question to include a small and complete example, as well as the exact error message.

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2013-11-21**:
Sounds like you might forgot to put a #include <nav_msgs/OccupancyGrid.h> into your source file. Still, lindzey´s comment applies: Post code, then people can make informed comments.

**Comment by [balakumar-s](https://answers.ros.org/users/5452/balakumar-s/) on 2013-11-21**:
It was a simple mistake, OccupancyGrid was typed as OccupacyGrid. Thanks for your help. :)